# Using Python to download files from Box

Tags: python, excel, download, box

I'm trying to use Python to download an Excel file to my local drive from Box.

Using the boxsdk I was able to authenticate via OAuth2 and successfully get the file id on Box.

However when I use the `client.file(file_id).content()` function, it just returns a string, and if I use `client.file(file_id).get()` then it just gives me a `boxsdk.object.file.File`.

Does anybody know how to write either of these to an Excel file on the local machine? Or a better method of using Python to download an excel file from Box.

(I discovered that `boxsdk.object.file.File` has an option `download_to(writeable_stream` [here](http://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boxsdk.object.html) but I have no idea how to use that to create an Excel file and my searches haven't been helpful).

Comment: You are most of the way there. What's left should be easier than what you've already done. If I'm reading the Box docs right, you just need to open a new, writable file in binary mode, and use that file (the Python file object, not the name of the file) as the parameter to `download_to()`. Check out Python's `open()` built-in function.

Comment: Thanks John Y, that worked! I used the open() function with the arguments 'wb' (for mode) and 1 (for buffer). As long as I had already created a blank excel file in the local drive then it wrote the downloaded data into the excel sheet (including separating it into different tabs). Excel wasn't happy when I tried to open the excel file manually, but as long as I used the close() function first then it was possible to open the excel tabs as dataframes in Python using pandas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that the documentation and source for `download_to` can be found [here](http://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boxsdk.object.html?highlight=download_to#boxsdk.object.file.File.download_to) and [here](http://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boxsdk/object/file.html#File.download_to). I learned about it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315500/778533) myself. You just need to do the following

```
path = 'anyFileName.xlsx'
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    client.file(file_id).download_to(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to read my excel files from box and you can check the content character type and use that when decoding.

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth
from boxsdk import Client
import io
import pandas as pd
import chardet # for checking char type

# Configure JWT auth object
sdk = JWTAuth.from_settings_file('config/box_config.json')
# Get auth client
client = Client(sdk)

s = client.file(file.id).content()
print(chardet.detect(open(s, 'rb').read())['encoding']) # gives char type
outputDF = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use python [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), along with dialect='excel' flag. It works really nice for exporting data to Microsoft Excel. 
The main idea is to use csv.writer inside a loop for writing each line. Try this and if you can't, post the code here.